# iPhone distribution certificate no private key

Tags: ios, certificate

We share an account with another developer.  Do I need the private key from them to create an app at our site?  Can I create a separate distribution cert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You can create your own Distribution Certificate and use it. However, it preferred to be one Distribution Certificate shared between all team members to avoid frequent invalid Provisioning profiles.

Good Luck

Comment: Great thanks!  So I have to generate a private key from my machine?

Comment: Sure, just request a new certificate from keychain and upload it to Apple Developer portal to generate your new certificate.